# Oracle XML parsing failed , invalid character found in a Name or Nmtoken

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The below code works well for non-integers well .
I've several tags with integers ( say `<1>` , `<2>` etc),

```
SET serveroutput ON
alter session set cursor_sharing = exact;
with xmldata(d) as (select xmltype('<ROWSET><ROW><1>ABC</1></ROW></ROWSET>') from dual
)
select x.*
FROM xmldata,
     xmltable('ROWSET/ROW' passing xmldata.d
              columns
              name varchar2(10) path '1'
     ) x
;
```

I've tried using this also:

```
DECLARE
l_xml xmltype;
l_val VARCHAR2(1000) := '<ROWSET><ROW><1>ABC</1></ROW></ROWSET>';
BEGIN
     l_xml        := xmltype(l_val);
end;
```

Both leads to an error below:

```
Error report:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00231: invalid character 49 ('1') found in a Name or Nmtoken
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 5
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Thanks in advance and appreciations:)

Comment: What Oracle version are you running?

Comment: Eeek....that's the base release for 11gR2.  I *strongly* recommend upgrading to 11.2.0.4.0 ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't need to know the Oracle version (but in general, it's good practice to always provide it when asking a question).

The error, LPX-00231, seems to be self explanatory.  You can't start the name with a number.  If you change the code to read:

```
SET serveroutput ON
alter session set cursor_sharing = exact;
with xmldata(d) as (select xmltype('<ROWSET><ROW><A1>ABC</A1></ROW></ROWSET>') from dual
)
select x.*
FROM xmldata,
     xmltable('ROWSET/ROW' passing xmldata.d
              columns
              name varchar2(10) path '1'
     ) x
;
```

Then it works fine.

Hope that helps....

Comment: Hope you meant `path `'A1'` and I knew it works.. So, will my query works well in (`11.2.0.4.0`) and above for my query ? Was this only the problem with my current version (`11.2.0.1.0`) ?

Comment: No, you misunderstand.  The Oracle version is irrelevant, because the bug is in your code, not Oracle.  You can't have a tag (not sure if that's the correct term), that starts with a digit (0-9).  So, <1>ABC</1> is not valid.  When I changed it to <A1>ABC</A1>, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The error:

```
LPX-00231: invalid character 49 ('1') found in a Name or Nmtoken
```

is because in your XML you have an element `1`:

```
<1>ABC</1>
```

where `<1>` is a [start tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-starttags) (and `</1>` is an [end tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-starttags)).  In tags `1` is [the name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-Name) that gives the element's type. The names have certain [naming rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-common-syn):

> [Definition: A Name is a token beginning with a letter or one of a few punctuation characters, and continuing with letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, colons, or full stops, together known as name characters.] Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.

and

> The first character of a Name MUST be a NameStartChar, and any other characters MUST be NameChars; this mechanism is used to prevent names from beginning with European (ASCII) digits or with basic combining characters. Almost all characters are permitted in names, except those which either are or reasonably could be used as delimiters.

The exact definitions of `Name` and `NameStartChar` are [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-common-syn).

As usual a more human friendly explanation is found from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp):

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
>
> Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
>
> Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
>
> Names cannot contain spaces
>
> Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

**Summary:**

Always start your element names with a letter - use `COL1` instead `1COL`.